# Getting error when creating a hierarchy in variations in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, variations

I am attempting to create a fr-FR with english UI variation. But when I run it, I get these errors in the logs. As well the "Is Hierarchy Created" remains at No.

The bottom message indicates the site already exists which might be ok. The first I think means the list already existed?

```
SpawnVariationSitesJob for web 'http://mysite/en-us' catches Exception when processing job type CreateList System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.    
 at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.MultiLingualResourceList.CreateMultiLingualVariations(PublishingWeb parentArea, VariationLabel targetLabel, CachedVariationSettings variationSettings, IVariationsLog lroLogger, List`1 errors)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.SpawnSitesJobDefinition.PerformVariationListSpawn(PublishingWeb currentArea, SpawnSitesPayLoadItem spawnProperties, VariationLabel varLabel, CachedVariationSettings settings, IVariationsLog lroLogger, List`1 errors)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.SpawnSitesJobDefinition.PerformVariationsSpawn(SPWorkItem workItem, SPWeb currentWeb, CachedVariationSettings variationSettings) StackTrace: 
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (sig=9afccfd8-248d-4fb9-a01a-c8bacd6f7473|2|microsoft.office.server.native.pdb, offset=135DA)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (offset=21F8D)










 PublishingWeb::CreateVariationWithSpecificTitleUrl(), web = 'http://mysite/en-us/aboutus/GlobalPlatform/GlobalPortal' and varLabel = 'fr-fr' catches Exception.  Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.VariationsOperationException: A new site variation was not created for source site http://mysite/en-us/aboutus/GlobalPlatform/GlobalPortal under target site http://mysite/fr-fr/aboutus/GlobalPlatform/GlobalPortal because a site with the same name already exists on the target. Delete or rename the existing target site or rename the source site, then click "New Site Variation" for the source site and attempt to create a new site variation in target label fr-fr again.    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb.CreateVariationWithSpecificTitleUrl(CachedVariationSettings variationSettings, VariationLabel varlabel, String variantUrlName, String variantTitle, Boolean isCreateHierarchies, IVariationsLog lroLogger) StackTrace: 
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (sig=9afccfd8-248d-4fb9-a01a-c8bacd6f7473|2|microsoft.office.server.native.pdb, offset=135DA)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (offset=21F8D)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first error indicates that the list already exists.

And I suggest you could create another variation site with the different site name.